# Simplify $\frac{\sin(ax)\cosh(bx)+\frac{a}{b}\cos(ax)\sinh(bx)}{\sin(ax)\sinh(bx)+\frac{a}{b}\cos(ax)\cosh(bx)}$

Tags: trigonometry, mathematical-physics, hyperbolic-functions

The equation
$$\frac{\sin(ax)\cosh(bx)+\frac{a}{b}\cos(ax)\sinh(bx)}{\sin(ax)\sinh(bx)+\frac{a}{b}\cos(ax)\cosh(bx)}$$
appears frequently in quantum mechanics to represent the time delays incurred from reflecting off of an infinite barrier adjacent to a potential well. Is there any means to simplify it? I considered trying to expand the formula in terms of complex exponentials or special functions, but I was largely unsuccessful. I also tried writing the numerator as a derivative of a function using the product rule, but that only complicated matters further.

Comment: Being quantum mechanist, I faced this kind of problem but my goal was to have good and simple approximations in order to save a lot a computing time. But this was only for small values of $x$ at least smaller than the first vertical asymptote. If this is of any interest for you, let me know.. By the way, you cannot simplify the expression (except if $a=b$).